Gitlab-runner 500 error after Gitlab upgrade
After upgrading Gitlab to 17.4.1, Gitlab-runner stopped working.
When trying to create a new runner via the UI Runners page, am receiving the following error.
'Response not successful: Received status code 500'
Have uninstalled Gitlab-runner and reinstalled, upgraded to latest version etc but still no luck. Have also tried the steps on the following page but still get the same issue. gitlab Error 500 after updating when viewing projects
Any ideas on how to resolve?
